# BeautifulSoup seemingly-randomly scapes 23, 42 or 87 results from the page despite there being 100

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy

**EDIT/UPDATE:** I started using BeautifulSoup as alecxe mentioned below, but now I receive a seemingly random range of results.  Sometimes it returns 23, most of the time 42 and sometimes 87. If I re-scape the same page I don't get the same results. 95% of the time it retrieves 42 items...
Anybody have an idea what's going on?
[image: Here's a poorly cropped version of the varying results] (full-size link here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSZ3L.png)

I used similar code to Alecxe's seen here but I beleive both have the same issue

```
def parse(self, response):
data = json.loads(response.body)['results_html']
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

prices = [float(price.strip(r"\r\n\t").replace('$','').split(" ")[0]) 
          for price in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"USD"))]
```

Part of my code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/y7hypCmv

(Previous) *For whatever reason my scraper insists on grabbing 19 page results opposed to the 100 that are available. Here's my spider:*

```
from scrapy import Request, Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from idem.items import IdemItem


URL = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start={page}&count=100' # Note, this is pre-formatted HTML

class MySpider(Spider):
    handle_httpstatus = 200
    name = "postings"

    def start_requests(self):
        index = 0
        while True:
            yield Request(URL.format(page=index))
            index +=100
            if index >= 200: break
    def parse(self,response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = []
        item = IdemItem()
        item["price"] = sel.xpath("//text()[contains(.,'$')]").extract()
        item["supply"] = sel.xpath("//span[@class[contains(.,'market_listing_num')]]/text()").extract()
        item["_id"] = sel.xpath("//span[@class[contains(.,'market_listing_item_name')]]/text()[1]").extract()

        for price, supply, _id in zip(item["price"], item["supply"], item["_id"]):
            item = IdemItem()
            item["price"] = float(price.strip(r"\r\n\t").replace('$',''))
            item["supply"] = int(supply.strip(r"\r\n\t").replace(',',''))
            item["_id"] = _id.strip(r"\r\n\t").replace(r'u2605','\u2605').decode('unicode-escape')
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

I can pull all the data if I change count=19 and index +=19, but I'd rather just scrape all 100 listings at the same time!

Here's the shell result after scraping:

```
  'downloader/request_count': 2,
  'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
  'downloader/response_bytes': 31456,
  'downloader/response_count': 2,
  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
  'finish_reason': 'finished',
  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 10, 16, 13, 46, 409000),
  'item_scraped_count': 38, #-----(19 results x 2 pages)-------#
  'log_count/DEBUG': 80,
  'log_count/INFO': 7,
  'response_received_count': 2,
  'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
  'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 10, 16, 13, 44, 808000)}
```

Really any suggestion would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what is worked for me (requires [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to be installed):

```
def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)['results_html']
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

    prices = [float(price.strip(r"\r\n\t").replace('$','').split(" ")[0]) 
              for price in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"USD"))]
```

Prices would be a list like this:

```
[0.08, 0.08, 0.04, 0.08, 0.05, 0.11, 0.08, 0.03, 0.06, 0.07, 0.06, 0.06, 0.11, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.07, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.12, 0.08, 0.07, 0.11, .
 ...
 0.04, 0.11, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.09, 0.06, 0.12, 0.04, 0.06, 0.07, 0.04, 0.05, 0.04]
```

FYI, I've tried different location techniques, but haven't made it work with `Scrapy`-only.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I tried it with BeautifulSoup and can only scrape 42 or 44 results.
Any idea how to get all 100?

Comment: I just noticed something odd:
It appears that the scraper will either return results of 21-23, 42-43 or 86-87. About 95% of the time it will return 43 though...
Anybody have any idea what's going on?

Comment: @5Y3WS are you using the same exact code as provided in the answer and the target url is the same?

Comment: I tried to teach myself BeautifulSoup so I kind of made a hybrid with the old one.
Code was too long to post here: http://pastebin.com/y7hypCmv (Note: I removed some of the fields) It returned 46 upon posting this.

Comment: @5Y3WS check that you import the correct bs version: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. Your code works for me (100 items per page).

Comment: @alexce Oh really? That's good news at least.
Can you maybe post all the modules you're importing from? I have a feeling that's where I'm going wrong. Thanks for your help in all of this, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @alexce Ahh, the issue is within my pipelines.py. Duplicate key errors :o

Comment: @alexce Scratch that, I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm a mess, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

For whatever reason the BeautifulSoup HTML parser was getting confused and not returning the correct number of results.

I fixed this by utilizing Python's built in HTML parser and it consistently returns 100 results.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
```